# Jquery Select2 Dropdown issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2-4

I am using select 2 4.0 plugin, i have used the following set of codes for a mulitple input feild...

```
$(".learningsoughtgardian").select2({
  width: 'resolve',
  maximumSelectionLength: 4,
  placeholder: 'Eg: Physics,German,etc',
  closeOnSelect: false,
  templateResult: function(data) {
    var $res = $('<span></span>');
    var $check = $('<input type="checkbox" />');

    $res.text(data.text);

    if (data.element) {
      $res.prepend($check);
      $check.prop('checked', data.element.selected);
    }

    return $res;
  }
});
```

the `closeonselect: false` keeps the drop down open, `maximumselectionlength: 4` means that I can add up maximum of 4 elements in the box..and `templateResult:` adds a checkbox beside each field..

when I use the above code, the maximum number of select part gets void and I can select more than 4 items...

please help me out...

Comment: It could be just because of `closeonselect:false`, No where in their docs they have mentioned the example this way.. You can raise this issue in GIT...

Comment: Execute this code `$(".js-example-basic-multiple-limit").select2({
  maximumSelectionLength: 2,
  closeOnSelect: false
});` in console of their **[example site](https://select2.github.io/examples.html)** and you can see the same behavior in their site too.. So they do not have testcase for this.. Raise an issue and ask for fix.. :)

Comment: It's a known issue, `maximumSelectionLength` is only checked when the drop down is opened.